# Root filesystem nearly full - should I be worried?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, root-filesystem, df

```
me@netbook:~$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             323M  292M   15M  96% /
tmpfs                 5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /lib/init/rw
tmpfs                 100M  740K   99M   1% /run
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                 368M   11M  339M   3% /tmp
udev                  492M     0  492M   0% /dev
tmpfs                 199M  240K  199M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda10             91G   80G  6.0G  94% /home
/dev/sda9             368M   11M  339M   3% /tmp
/dev/sda6             8.3G  6.2G  1.7G  79% /usr
/dev/sda7             2.8G  538M  2.1G  21% /var
/dev/sdb1             1.9G  1.5G  471M  76% /media/usb0
```

I got GNOME's warning about my root filesystem being filled up. But using `baobab` to try and figure out what is clogging the already quite small root filesystem confused me. *And all of these partitions were assigned automatically based on percentages anyway*... Is it such a bad thing to have 15M left on the root filesystem? And if so, then why did the Debian installer only assign a very small percentage of the available free space for that purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse you should be worried but no need to panic since  that you have seperate partitions for /var and /usr, that makes up for isolation of most often written and logged data which is good ; its important to have atleast some amount of free space (say 10% or 20% free space/reservation on all the filesystems) always around and you are not sure what requirement is going to strike around. Its pretty important to have all the important filesystems such /, /usr, /var, /tmp (and on some hosts /usr/local) have some amount of free space.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have kernels you aren't using. They can take up a lot of room, and Debian's automatic package management tends to leave old kernels behind. For example, if you're running kernel `2.6.32-5-686` (output of `uname -r`), you don't need `linux-image-2.6.32-4-686` any more.

For future reference, there's hardly any point nowadays in separating the `/usr` and `/var` from the rest of the system partition.

Comment: only one kernel on the affected machine. any other ideas as to what it might be?

Comment: @ixtmixilix Old kernels are the only thing I can think of that are commonly around and dispensable. Post the output from `du -x /`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be /lib and /lib64 (if it exists) that is causing this.

They may fill up faster than you want if you run some chrooted environments or install additional software.

Comment: @Mat right - I changed my answer. I was not aware that even /sbin/ executables are linked to /lib or /lib64.